# KML - Polygon Fill not needed, but still happens

Tags: kml

I have KML code that will fill a polygon.  I do not want the polygon filled.  I have 0 and 1 but still displays a filled polygon.  The polygon is approximately 10m radius.  Is this so small that the line width of 1.5 is actually causing the polygon to be filled?
Here is the KML (I stripped it to only 1 point rather than the multiple of the original source)(this is operational so you should be able to copy it and see what I mean):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>
<Document>
<name>
CO0xxxxxx
</name>
<open>1</open>
<Style id='a'>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
 http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-blank.png
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
<open>0</open>
<name>Names</name>
<Placemark>
<name>WELL NO 2</name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
<Point>
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
<coordinates>-107.676117, 39.586253,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<open>0</open>
<name>Polygons on-off</name>
<Placemark>
<Style>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>root://icons/palette-s.png</href>
<x>224</x>
<y>224</y>
<w>32</w>
<h>32</h>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<Fill>0</Fill>
<Outline>1</Outline>
</PolyStyle>
<LineStyle>
<Color>ff0000ff</Color>
<Width>1.5</Width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
<Polygon>
<extrude>0</extrude>
<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-107.676029,39.586323,0
-107.675996,39.586227,0
-107.676085,39.586158,0
-107.676205,39.586183,0
-107.676238,39.586279,0
-107.676149,39.586348,0
-107.676029,39.586323,0
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

KML is a dialect of XML. Tags are case sensitive.

([from the posted KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160930.kml))

```
<PolyStyle>
 <Fill>0</Fill>
 <Outline>1</Outline>
</PolyStyle>
```

is not the same as:

```
<PolyStyle>
 <fill>0</fill>
 <outline>1</outline>
</PolyStyle>
```

([updated KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160930_lc.kml))

[KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polystyle)